# Loop inside divs with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop inside divs which have the same class name.
It's in order to get the correct query string which I want to use for a getJSON afterward.
The problem is that I can't get the various arguments from the divs...

Here is the code creating the divs (this one works fine, I checked with Chrome console) :

```js
$(InputsWrapper).append('<div>' + '<div class="name" id="InputsWrapper_'+field.id+'">' + '<label>' +field.button_title+ ' </label>' +
         '<input type="text" name="mytext-'+field.titre+'" table='+field.table+' titre='+field.titre+' id="field_'+field.titre+'" placeholder="'+field.placeholder+'"/>' + ' ' + '<button class="removeclass3"> x </button>' + '<br>' + '</div>' + '</div>');
            $("body").on("click", ".removeclass3", function() {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); // To Remove Filter
            return false;
            });
            $(InputsWrapperDisplay).append('<div>' + '<div class="name" table="'+field.table+'" titre="'+field.titre+'" id="InputsWrapperDisplay-'+field.id+'">' + '<label>' +field.button_title+'</label>' + ' ' + '<button class="removeclass3"> x </button>' + '</div>' + '</div>');
            $("body").on("click", ".removeclass3", function() {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); // To Remove Display
            return false;
            });
```

```html
<div id="InputsWrapper"></div>
<div id="InputsWrapperDisplay"></div>

<div class="name" id="InputsWrapper_TI"><label>TI </label><input type="text" name="mytext-TI" table="technical_item" titre="TI" id="field_TI" placeholder="Nom partiel ou complet"> <button class="removeclass3"> x </button><br></div>
```

Here is the code which is supposed to modify the myjson variable :

```
var myjson = "http://****/get_json_test.php?callback=?";
  $('.name').each(function(i, obj){
     if(document.getElementById('field_'+obj.titre+'') != null){
        if(document.getElementById('field_'+obj.titre+'').value != null){
           myjson += '&mytext-'+obj.table+'|'+obj.titre+'=' + document.getElementById('field_'+obj.titre+'').value;
        }
     }
  });

  $('.display').each(function(i,obj){
     if(document.getElementById('InputsWrapperDisplay-'+obj.id+'') != null){
        myjson += '&'+obj.table+'|'+obj.titre+'';
     }
  });
  console.log(myjson);
```

I get this result : "http://******/get_json_test.php?callback=?"

Would anyone know why I don't get the modifications in myjson ?

Thanks,
Corentin.

Comment: Please show your HTML

Comment: Code snippets are designed to run your HTML/JS/CSS all together. If you combine your JS into one snippet and add your relevent HTML code for your JS it will be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Please do not mix Native `JS` and `jQuery`.

Comment: why is that @LShetty if you do not mind to share :)

Comment: @kanJi sure, it's just ugly :) :D

Comment: The problem is that I already use a Json to get the differents divs and buttons, so I can't post all my html, js and php code :/ Actually I'm just trying to know if I have mistakes in my syntax with the js and jquery ? I added an example of the div created by my js function, hope it can help you to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
$('.name').each(function(i, obj){
   if(document.getElementById('field_'+obj.titre+'') != null){
       ...
   }
});
```

You are iterating through all `.name`s, and then using its `titre` attibute to find its `field_<titre>` element, but your `div.name` element doensn't contain any `titre` attribute, see:

```
<div class="name" id="InputsWrapper_TI">...</div>
```

And after that, you're trying to access the `field_<titre>` attributes, but referencing to the `.name` element (the `obj` variable):

```
myjson += '&mytext-'+obj.table+'|'+obj.titre+'=' + document.getElementById('field_'+obj.titre+'').value;
```

---

To resolve the unmodified resultant string issue, I suggest the following solution (that doesn't require any change to your html):

```
$('.name').each(function(i, obj){
   var fieldElement = $(obj).find('input');
   if (fieldElement.length && fieldElement.val()) {
         myjson += '&mytext-' + fieldElement.attr('table') + '|' + fieldElement.attr('titre') + '=' + fieldElement.val();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have some results in "myjson", still not perfect but I will look into it.

Comment: @CocoFlouq Hehe, I saw that it wouldn't be perfect, but it would help you moving forward instead of being stuck. That's why I stated `...to resolve the unmodified resultant string issue...`. Anyway, I'm glad it worked! Good luck on your work!

Comment: Thanks again @falsarella, I succeeded to get what I need for the .filter but I have some issues with the .display. I tried a "var fieldElement = $(obj).find('div');" followed by a fieldElement.attr('table') to get the value from table in "<div class="display" table="technical_item" titre="TI"> but it seems that the .find("div") doesn't return what is into it, do I need to change all the divs name or is there an other solution ?

Comment: @CocoFlouq Since `.display` already has the `table` and `titre` attributes, you can get them with `$(obj).attr('table');`  and `$(obj).attr('titre');`. You need to study it more. See jQuery [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [traversing](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) documentation for further guidance, and [try jQuery](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery) course.

Comment: "myjson" works fine now :D Don't know why I was looking so complicated for .display, maybe because I definitely should read more seriously the jquery documentation ;) Thanks a lot anyway, you've been really helpful !

Answer (score 0):

In the each you are gaining a jQuery element and it can't have a `titre` or `table` property coming from your data-source.

You can add these property as dom data-attributes and use them latter.

Like:

```
var field = {id:50,button_title:'demo',titre:'foo', placeholder: 'bar', table: 'tab'}

$('#InputsWrapper').append('<div>' + '<div class="name" id="InputsWrapper_'+field.id+'" data-titre="'+field.titre+'" data-table="'+field.table+'">' + '<label>' +field.button_title+ ' </label>' +
         '<input type="text" name="mytext-'+field.titre+'" table='+field.table+' titre='+field.titre+' id="field_'+field.titre+'" placeholder="'+field.placeholder+'"/>' + ' ' + '<button class="removeclass3"> x </button>' + '<br>' + '</div>' + '</div>');
            $("body").on("click", ".removeclass3", function() {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); // To Remove Filter
            return false;
            });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6ym3e0eL/

But please consider to:

1. build your dynamic HTML in a more mantainable way
2. avoid mixing jQuery and vanilla code to access the DOM